# Why ADEumScreenshotOperationsController crash occurs?

Tags: ios, crash, screenshot, stack-trace

My last release an error starts to occur I saw it on my crash report tool but I have not any idea and I can not find any solution about it.

Has anyone experienced that problem before? 
Could you please suggest any solution option?

**About error log:**

```
-[ADEumScreenshotOperationsController observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:]
```

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException

`-[NSOperationQueue addOperation:]:` operation is already enqueued on a queue

**This is a stack trace:**

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x181e6a364 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1810b0528 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x181e6a2ac -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  Foundation                     0x1828427a0 __addOperations
4  LCWaikiki                      0x101085a54 -[ADEumScreenshotOperationsController observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:]
5  Foundation                     0x182772894 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver
6  Foundation                     0x1827723bc NSKeyValueDidChange
7  Foundation                     0x18282a68c NSKeyValueDidChangeWithPerThreadPendingNotifications
8  Foundation                     0x1827714c4 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:]
9  Foundation                     0x182843894 __NSOQSchedule_f
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x1817e6a14 _dispatch_client_callout
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x1817eef08 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x1817ed80c _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke$VARIANT$mp
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x1817f3cf4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x1817f3a38 _dispatch_worker_thread3
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x181a8f06c _pthread_wqthread
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x181a8eb6c start_wqthread
```

Answer (score 0):

I found reason of *ADEumScreenshotOperationsController* crash:

It's about **AppDynamics SDK** our project uses it and because of AppDynamics SDK that crash start to occurs.